# Change line printer port to be used by gw-basic program

Tags: printing

How to use lpt2 as the "line printer" in a gw-basic program.  The goal is to change the printer port to lpt2 so i can use the "net use"  command to redirect the printer output to a network printer.  I can redirect lpt1 to the network printer but have to disable the hardware printer in device manager.  However, I get the error printer is offline message.

All this is necessary to get data from the old program data files.  I plan to reprint, OCR and import into new software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the emulator [PC-BASIC](http://pcbasic.sourceforge.net/) to run your GW-BASIC program, read its data files and connect it to any printer. Point PC-BASIC to the printer by running it from the command line as

`pcbasic --lpt1:PRINTER:MyNetworkPrinterName --print-trigger=page`

where you replace `MyNetworkPrinterName` with the name of your printer in the operating system. If you want all output collected in a single print batch, replace `--print-trigger=page` with `--print-trigger=close`.

However, you mention that your final aim is to import the data into another program. A better solution,  avoiding the error-prone and labour-intensive scanning and OCR step, might be to let PC-BASIC print to a file directly:

`pcbasic --lpt1:FILE:MyOutputFile.txt`

which will send the print output to a UTF-8 text file.